# Cloud Firestore multiple documents and unknown collection path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore database with real time updates on web javascript app.
The purpose is to show sensor data (temperature, ultrasonic, etc) for each existent device:

```
devices/devices01/sensors/sensor01/value:10
devices/devices01/sensors/sensor02/value:15
devices/devices02/sensors/sensor01/value:30
devices/devices03/sensors/sensor01/value:20
```

The user can have a list of devices it wants to get sensors data real-time updated.

```
users/userA/devices/{device01:true,device03:true}
users/userB/devices/{device02:true}
```

I don't know how to query and get the snapshots when:
 1. Use device name from a list of devices
 2. Get all sensors on change

Of course, this doesn't work:

```
db.collection("devices").doc("[device01,device03]").collection("pins").doc("*").get()
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify each document individually and attach a listener to them all.  There are no list-like or wildcard methods to refer to documents.

The only way you can listen to multiple documents at once is when you're able to identify them all with a query.  The only kind of query that might help you here is one that identifies all the documents under `pins`.  A CollectionReference is a query that listens to all the documents in that collection.

Comment: Could you give me one suggestion how to do that?

Comment: Start with the samples in the documentation and build from there.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: OMG! Doug Stevenson? Are you real? Man, I am your fan, dude. Thanks for supporting us.

Comment: array_contains won't help you here.  It checks for a value within an array field stored in a document, not some arbitrary array that you pass in.  Not sure what the other option will get you.

Comment: O found 2 options:
1. As @todd-kerpelman suggested in this video <https://youtu.be/IdKEhWAV-kE?t=1m54s> I can use something like `.whereField("userList.uid").isGreaterThan(nil)`
2. As Jeff (from Angular Firebase) in this video <https://youtu.be/4t2eHrFW_0M?t=2m1s> I can use `.where("userList","array-contains","uid")` based on JavaScript SDK Release Notes Version 5.3.0 - July 19, 2018

Comment: you are correct. Array didn't work for this case because I cannot perform "where" method based on a document in the middle of the path if I want to get real-time changes in a document on the leaf.

Comment: I moved the list of user to the leaf, and it works to me now.